# Изменение ориентации телефона

Tags: jquery, mobile, javascript

Приветствую, хотел бы поинтересоваться. В JQuery Mobile существует событие `orientationchange`. Работает при повороте 0, 90, -90, 180.
Есть ли альтернативное событие на каком-нибудь js-фреймворке, которое связано со встряхиванием телефона или при любом повороте телефона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам решил - свою проблему, может кому пригодится.

Подключаем js-библиотеку [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), у данного фреймворка есть доступ к API телефона.

Данный метод называется - [Accelerometer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.0/phonegap_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#Accelerometer), пример реализации можно посмотреть там же.